# SQLite through Mainframe

Tags: sqlite, cobol, mainframe, jcl

- We have a batch Mainframe JCL and SQLite file in windows Share Path
- We need the data in windows share path periodically updated based on a mainframe computation.
- So We need to create records in the SQLite database based on Mainframe JCL/Cobol program and then manipulate it using SQLite.

Is this feasible? We are not able to find any leads on how to make use of SQLite from a Mainframe stand point. Any information would be very helpful.

Comment: No-one on the internet knows what software, standards, procedures, and mthods of doing things your site has. The chance of finding useful content somewhere which *happens entirely by codincidence* to be remotely close to what you may be able to use is very, very, slim, and even then you won't have sufficient access authority to even consider using it. You have to talk to the Mainframe people and discover what solution they want *before you even start your system design*. There have been several of these questions in the last few weeks. Talk to the Mainframe people. Else you will get nowhere.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" because there are so many different ways to solve this problem, all of which are dependent on your shop's configuration and standards.

Comment: The answer is 'Yes it's feasible'. However the details of the implementation are up to you and your support people as there are a myriad of ways to implement this. Just one approach would be to take the output from your batch program, reformat it (if necessary) and then transmit it over to your Windows server where it is used as input to the  database update process.

Comment: Appears your question was ahead of its time.  Looks like you can now get SQLite 3.21 for the mainframe [link]http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/SQLite-3-21-on-IBM-Mainframe-z-OS-td99559.html

Answer (score 1):

Someone's probably going to have to write a CICS routine for you. It might be a better idea to have a program run at your end at the set time(s) and invoke the Mainframe CICS program through yours using web services.

Since the question says that you're dependent on Mainframe calculations, you will have to make sure that you call the CICS program with all the required parameters and values or make sure that it can fetch those natively. Have the CICS program do the computations for you and return the results.

It might also be possible that what you refer to as "Mainframe JCL / COBOL program" (i.e. batch) already has a CICS (online) counterpart and you wouldn't have to write (or make someone write for you) a new routine again. Your Mainframe team should be able to confirm.

Comment: Why use CICS, why not run a batch program and transmit a file which is then loaded into the DB

Comment: As per Bruce, I'd personally probably go the SQLIte adherrent SQL route regarding the content's of the file. Although, at a guess, something like 90+% (very likely a very low figure) of MF-PC partnerships do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SSH server and serve the data from a file on the HFS side.
You can also FTP to a Wintel Stack (with NETRC DDNAME).

Yes you can serve WEB/REST from CICS as well (overkill), or use MQSeries (ditto), or even SMTP. Scrape 3270, EHLLAPI (obscure), third party products like XCOM.

Again the USS (OMVS) side, you should be able to sftp (-b) with a script. BPXBATCH is your friend....

A great many shops have been doing these things and more for a very long time.